# Rendering Radio Buttons Individually in WTForms/Jinja2

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a contact manager with Flask for a community group, and I'm working on the function to export contacts as a spreadsheet. I want to export either all contacts, only those who have been assigned to a ticket seller, only those assigned to a **specific** ticket seller, or those assigned to **no** ticket seller.

The form layout I want is something like this:

- RadioButton: All Sellers
- RadioButton: Select Seller

  - SelectField: Seller ID
- RadioButton: No Seller Assigned

with a select field tucked in between two of the radio buttons. This requires that I render the radio buttons individually, rather than letting Jinja render them as a group. This is possible, but **referencing** each individual button for rendering has proven difficult.

Here's the Jinja code I've come up with:

```
{% for subfield in form.sellers_filter %}
  {% if subfield.id.endswith('0') %}
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      {{ subfield.label }} {{ subfield }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if subfield.id.endswith('1') %}
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      {{ subfield.label }} {{ subfield }}
      {{ form.seller }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if subfield.id.endswith('2') %}
    <div class="form.group col-4">
      {{ subfield.label }} {{ subfield }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm bothered, though, by the `subfield.id.endswith()` part, and I'm hoping someone can suggest a more elegant solution.

For reference, here is my form code:

```
def list_sellers():
    c1 = aliased(Contact)
    c2 = aliased(Contact)
    return db.session.query(c2).
        select_from(c1).join(c2, c2.id==c1.seller_id).
        filter(c1.seller_id != None)
    
class ExportForm(FlaskForm):
    filtered = BooleanField('Apply Filters')
    sellers_filter = RadioField(
        'Filter by Seller',
        choices=[
            ('all', 'All Sellers'),
            ('select', 'Select Seller'),
            ('none', 'No Seller')
        ],
        validators=[Optional()]
    )
    seller = QuerySelectField(
        'Seller',
        query_factory=list_sellers,
        allow_blank=False,
        validators=[Optional()],
        render_kw={'class': 'form-select'},
    )
    submit = SubmitField('Download')
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late, but you can do this using the radio button's label field as follows

```
{% if subfield.label.text == 'Select Seller' %}
```

As per [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926721/comparing-wtforms-field-label-to-string-always-returns-false)